# Ionic http request not working in apk

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm working on an android app using the ionic framework, in my code i do send a get request to a server to get a list of some data,

```
var URI = 'http://192.168.10.7:8080/app/rest';
$http.get(URI+"/articles") ...
```

the code works fine when a test with `ionic serve` the get request works fine and i get the list of my data, but when i generate the APK file and deploy it, the request doesn't seem to work i don't get the list of data, knowing that my device is connected to the same network to server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly likely that you are running your server locally at the address `http://192.168.10.7:8080`. If you deploy your app to a device, and that device is no longer on your local network, or the server does not permit external access, then the app will be unable to communicate with it.

Comment: yes but my device and the server are conneted to the same network, and i've already done it with another app and it worked, but in this one it doesn't and doesn't work locally when i run the app on a emulator such as Ripple. thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried running the app with `ionic emulate android -l -c`? 
This will run the app as an apk on your device but will also output the console logs from the app. Perhaps you can write a single `console.log(response);` to test what the device is receiving back, or if the request is blocked.

It may also be the case that you need to add Content Security Policys to your index.html, but I would check what the error is before suggesting anymore steps.